# Dynamically changing Width and Height of Lottie anim in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, lottie

I'm working on a web app built in Django and React, I've a question about to change the width and height of my Lottie img when the screen change Its size.
That's my Lottie configuration:

```
  const defaultOptions = {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData: animation,
    rendererSettings: {
      preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice"
    }
  }

   <div id='lottie-container'>      
        <Lottie
        id='lottie-icon'
        options={defaultOptions}
        />
   </div>
```

That's CSS media query:

```
/*------|
Desktop |
-------*/

@media screen and (min-width:991px) {
    /* LOTTIE */
    #lottie-icon{
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }
}

/*-----|
Mobile |
------*/

@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
    /* LOTTIE */
    #lottie-icon{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here seems to be the way you assign an id to your Lottie component.

Here is how you can assign a class / id to your generated svg element (according to [this](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/wiki/Renderer-Settings)):

```
const defaultOptions = {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData: animation,
    rendererSettings: {
      preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice",
      className: "lottie-svg-class",
      id: "lottie-svg-id"
    }
  }
```

Then you can manipulate its size in your CSS, either by using media queries or using vw / vh.

You will need to add `!important` tags though in order to override the style properties of the svg:

```
.lottie-svg-class{
    width:calc(max(500px, 40vw))!important;
}
```

Comment: I know this is not related, but how do you load the JSON files dynamically for Lottie? If I want to design a dynamic menu and I want the icon (lottie) to change based on the file name passed to it

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `only` to your media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

}
```

Comment: In my case this process doesn't work, keep in mind that I'm using Lottie

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to use vw and vh or percentage instead of px. I usually tend to use them for responsiveness.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just give height and width to the `lottie-container` the lottie icon will take the height and width of the container.

```
/*------|
Desktop |
-------*/

@media screen and (min-width:991px) {
    #lottie-container{
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }
}

/*-----|
Mobile |
------*/

@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
    #lottie-container{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
}
```